# Generic Parser that outputs code in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I am writing a SIC/XE assembler (a sort of theoretical assembler). The problem comes when parsing the code. I have written a parser myself but having very little experience with parsing it has become bloated and messy.

Is there some sort of a parser library in C# where I could define sets of rules and the code would then be parsed properly and returned in some sort of a data structure /or format (like xml).

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: The other post is about parsers capable of parsing C# code. It is different than parsers in C#. Answering the question, yes there are some, they vary mainly how the parsing is performed (top-down, bottom-up) and how do you define the syntax. Since my parser does not qualify for the other question (I don't have grammar for C# language), but it fits the bill for your purpose -- take a look: https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/

Comment: @greenoldman Thanks I'll definitely look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at ANTLR. It's free but you might need to buy the book to learn how to use it. You can define grammars and it will generate a Lexer/Parser. You can use it to generate code in C#, Java and other languages.

Link: http://www.antlr.org/